# Immediately registering an event listener after initializing an Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write an Angular service which keeps track of the visited URLs within a single page Angular application that uses the `ngRoute` module. Therefore, I subscribe to the `$routeChangeStart` event and query the `$location.url()` function within the callback:

```
angular
    .module("myApplication")
    .factory("visitedUrls", visitedUrls);

visitedUrls.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$location"];

function visitedUrls($rootScope, $location) {
    return {
        registerListener: function() {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
                var url = $location.url();
                // ...
            });
        }
    };
}
```

However, the above approach won't register the event listener until the service has been resolved by the dependency injector for the first time — which is too late. I also want track all URLs visited before that.

My current workaround gets hold of the Angular injector and calls the `registerListener` method immediately after the application has been bootstrapped:

```
$angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApplication"]);

    var visitedUrls = angular.element(document).injector().get("visitedUrls");
    visitedUrls.registerListener();
});
```

I'm sure there is a better way to attach an event listener (from within a service) to `$rootScope` right after initializing an application, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`.run(...)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

```
angular.module('myApplication')
    .run(function(visitedUrls){
        visitedUrls.registerListener();
    });
```

You can annotate the DI however you want.

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you!